# PHP Usar Métodos mágicos ou não?

Tags: php

Surgiu uma duvida que eu acho interessante e gostaria de postar aqui.

Como vocês costumam usar métodos cuja funcionalidade é setar e resgatar atributos em uma `class`?

Usam assim:

```
public function setNome($nome)
```

Ou com métodos mágicos? Assim:

```
public function __set($attr,$valor)
```

Pergunto isso pelo fato de ver em códigos alheios, apesar de ter métodos mágicos muitos não usam.

Answer (score 3):

Nada impede que você utilize as duas formas, isso pode até ser de grande valia. Quando utilizo `PHP`, eu uso `get/set` e o nome dos campos, dessa forma:

```php
<?php
    class Cliente {
        private $id;
        private $nome;
        public function __construct($id = 0, $nome = NULL){
            $this->id   = $id;
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }
        public function getId(){
            return $this->id;
        }
        public function getNome(){
            return $this->nome;
        }
        public function setId($value){
            $this->id = $value;
        }
        public function setNome($value){
            $this->nome = $value;
        }

        public function __set ($name,$value){
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
        public function __get ($name){
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }


    $cliente = new Cliente();
    $cliente->id   = 1;
    $cliente->nome = "Fulano 1";

    echo $cliente->getId() . " " . $cliente->getNome();
```

Perceba que os `private $id` e `private $nome` estão sendo setados com os métodos mágicos e nos `getId()` e `getNome()` estou pegando os valores, ou seja, podem trabalhar juntos de maneira a permitir esse tipo de implementação.

***Exemplo:*** [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/5DouOG)

---

Outro fator importante é que você pode trabalhar com esse código de `set` no padrão [Fluent](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/03/19/implementing-fluent-interface-pattern-in-php/) dessa forma;

```php
<?php
    class Cliente {
        private $id;
        private $nome;
        public function __construct($id = 0, $nome = NULL){
            $this->id   = $id;
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }
        public function getId(){
            return $this->id;
        }
        public function getNome(){
            return $this->nome;
        }
        public function setId($value){
            $this->id = $value;
            return $this;
        }
        public function setNome($value){
            $this->nome = $value;
            return $this;
        }

        public function __set ($name,$value){
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
        public function __get ($name){
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }


    $cliente = new Cliente();

    $cliente->setId(2)
            ->setNome("Fulano 2");

    echo $cliente->id . " " . $cliente->nome;
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/FGTZ9R)

Logo após ser chamado o método `setId` chama-se o `setNome` (sucessivamente se tiver mais métodos [Fluent](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/03/19/implementing-fluent-interface-pattern-in-php/)), que é a lógica desse padrão. Então, tem uma flexibilidade que os métodos mágicos não te fornece, mas, os métodos public `set` podem ter.

Como relatado nada impede o trabalho em conjunto desses recursos em PHP. São métodos mágicos:

- [__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor)
- [__destruct](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor)
- [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)
- [__callStatic](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)
- [__get](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)
- [__set](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)
- [__isset](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)
- [__unset](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)
- [__sleep](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep)
- [__wakeup](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep)
- [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)
- [__invoke](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke)
- [__set_state](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.set-state)
- [__clone](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Referências:

- [Métodos Mágicos](http://www.php.net//manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php)
- [Implementing Reusable Fluent Interface Pattern in PHP With AOP](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/03/19/implementing-fluent-interface-pattern-in-php/)
- [The basics of Fluent interfaces in PHP](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-basics-of-fluent-interfaces-in-php/)

Comment: Antigamente os métodos mágicos implicavam uma perda de performance, mas não sei se hoje em dia isso ainda é relevante. É?

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu acredito que não pelo fato que os frameworks usam demais, mas, eu não posso afirmar em relação a performace tenho que dar uma pesquisada, se tiver algum artigo e queria indicar de site confiável a gente escreve isso nesse post vai enriquecer, mas, é a primeira pessoa que vejo falando nisso.

Comment: Eu não lembro de cabeça de nenhuma referência, mas vou pesquisar também e se achar eu te digo.

Comment: Achei algumas coisas, mas por enquanto só olhei por cima. Parece que magic properties e methods têm sim performance pior, mas o impacto disso vai sempre depender da aplicação (ou seja, de quando/quanto são usados). Links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3330852/825789, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6184337/825789, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3634748/825789, http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magic-benchmarks.

Comment: Tem esse também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697922/are-magic-methods-best-practice-in-php @bfavaretto, não tem um fator técnico ainda mas, se eu achar ou tu achar adicionamos!