# Como, quando e onde usar os métodos mágicos do PHP? Get e Set? Qual a diferença? Devo usá-los em todas as classes que eu criar?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou começando em POO e gostaria de saber quando, onde e como devo utilizar os métodos mágicos GET e SET e se possivel citar a suas diferenças na prática. Devo utiliza-las em todas as classes que eu criar? Como saberei se é necessário ou não usar? Poderiam me dar exemplos?

Answer (score 4):

Esta pergunta insere-se no tema desta: [PHP Usar Métodos mágicos ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21798/php-usar-m%C3%A9todos-m%C3%A1gicos-ou-n%C3%A3o)

No entanto a minha resposta acontece devido ao contexto sobre parte onde menciona:

> Devo utiliza-las em todas as classes que eu criar?

A resposta é simples, as técnicas existem para serem utilizadas mas depende muito dos casos. Muitos são os autores que se referem aos métodos mágicos `__GET` e `__SET` como mais lentos, mas a verdade é que podem dar jeito e nunca devemos deixar de os considerar. Passo a explicar:

```
class Pessoa {

    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    function getIdade() {
        return $this->idade;
    }

    function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    function setIdade($idade) {
        $this->idade = $idade;
    }
}
```

Imaginemos esta classe. Está na conformidade com a definição de programação por objectos também utilizado em outras linguagens de programação, que é claramente declarativa pelos métodos que implementa. Ou seja, definindo por exemplo uma variável interna com `private` na classe a única forma de afectar o seu conteúdo é pelos seus métodos de nome únicos para `$nome > Nome` e para `$idade > Idade`. Os prefixos `set` e `get`
são convenções utilizadas de forma a tornar o código legível por qualquer um. Para afectar o conteúdo e o outro para obter o conteúdo no momento da chamada do método, respectivamente.

No entanto o PHP e por ser um linguagem de script implementa um outro mecanismo que fere este protocolo o que por muitos é questionável mas tem na prática algumas "muita" utilidade. Vejamos um exemplo para a mesma classe:

```
class Pessoa {

    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public function __get($name) {
        switch (strtolower($name)){
            case 'nome':
                return $this->nome;
            case 'idade':
                return $this->idade;
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        switch (strtolower($name)){
            case 'nome':
                $this->nome = $value;
            case 'idade':
                $this->idade = $value;
        }
    }

}

$teste = new Pessoa();

$teste->nome = "jon";
echo $teste->nome;
```

Como pode observar a standard foi quebrado mas o fim continua o mesmo. Pessoalmente e profissionalmente penso que devemos seguir o protocolo que nos é imposto por um qualquer projecto, no entanto quando temos liberdade de implementação eu utilizo ambos dependendo de algumas situações.

Utilizo o **primeiro exemplo** quando são poucas variáveis como no exemplo indicado, por ser mais declarativo e já agora por ser muito útil nos editores de hoje em dia onde escrevemos o nosso código. Instanciamos um objecto digitamos o seu nome e temos logo acesso seus métodos e é só escolher... poupa muito tempo, para não falar de outras vantagens como implementação de standard, etc.

Utilizo o segundo exemplo quando são muitas variáveis. Imagine 10 variáveis na classe que pode aumentar com a implementação... no primeiro exemplo tem de colocar 10 métodos `SET` e 10 métodos `GET`. Este é um exemplo prático que resolve esse problema de *dimensão*:

```
class Pessoa {

    private $props = [];

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->props[strtolower($name)])) {
            return $this->props[strtolower($name)];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->props[strtolower($name)] = $value;
    }

}

$teste = new Pessoa();

$teste->nome = "jon";
echo $teste->nome;
```

Com pode observar com dois métodos simples consigo encapsular um infinito número de variáveis, que se manterão internas. No entanto e como *não existe uma bela sem um senão*, perde alguma forma de apoio ao código e no seguimento do exemplo dos editores de código mas existem outras... estes não o poderão ajudar se escrever mal o nome da variável e nunca será retornado nenhum erro o que na depuração em grandes projectos pode ser um problema. Assim:

```
$teste = new Pessoa();

$teste->nome = "jon";
echo $teste->nome;   // mostrará JON
echo $teste->nom;    // nada será mostrado
```

Espero ter explicado com casos práticos alguma utilidade sem ter entrado em documentação exaustiva que pode ler-se noutro local. Com esta resposta procuro apenas deixar alguns pontos que com a minha experiência tenho me confrontado.

Answer (score 2):

Em orientação a objetos o GET e o SET são utilizados para encapsular o atributo da classse para que ele não seja acessado diretamente.

**Criando a classe:**

```
<?php
 class Aluno(){
    private $nome;

  public function setNome($vNome){
   $this->nome= $vNome;
  }
  public function getNome(){
    return $this->nome;
  }
}
?>
```

Ao instanciar esta classe por exemplo o atributo nome está privado, neste caso ninguém consegue acessar ele além da própria classe. Então como vou setar o nome? Você vai setar através do método setNome().
É interessante fazer isto, pois dentro do setNome, você pode querer criar regras de negócio, como por exemplo um teste, se o nome for maior que 50 caracteres dar um aviso ao usuário e não aceitar.
Agora imagine esta classe sendo instanciada em 50 lugares diferentes dentro da sua aplicação, se você tivesse que alterar esta regra de negócio para aceitar no máximo 30 caracteres no nome, você simplesmente mudaria a regra no método setNome, automaticamente a regra mudaria nos 50 lugares, pois em todos os lugares o nome está sendo setado pelo método.
Se você setasse o valor diretamente no atributo nome e tornasse ele publico, você não conseguiria garantir que sua regra seria aplicada por outro desenvolvedor que fosse utilizar esta classe.

**Utilizando a classe:**

```
<?php
   include("aluno-class.php");
   $tempAluno = new Aluno(); 
   $tempAluno->setNome("DAVID"); 
   echo "<br/>Nome do Aluno : ".$tempAluno->getNome();
?>
```